# Using beatifulsoup to find text on html

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my first time using `beautifulsoup` as a scraper tool and I just follow thru slowly with each step.

I've used `soup.find_all("div", class_="product-box__inner")` find a list of element I want and this partiful stuff not going thru my mind right now. my question below,

here is the HTML and my target is "$0" and I have tried
`element.find("span", title= re.compile("$"))` and I can't use `element.select("dt > dd > span > span")` because there's multiple one with same tag format which I dont need at all, Is there way I can target span data-fees-annual-value="" to get .text working?

```
<div class="product-box__features-item">
    <dt class="f-body-3 product-box__features-label">Annual fee</dt>
    <dd class="f-title-5 product-box__features-text u-margin-0">
        <span>
            <span data-fees-annual-value="">$0</span>
        </span>
    </dd>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to your goal with `css selectors` and they could be used more specific and reference directly on the attribute `data-fees-annual-value`:

```
soup.select_one('span[data-fees-annual-value]').text
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""
<div class="product-box__features-item">
    <dt class="f-body-3 product-box__features-label">Annual fee</dt>
    <dd class="f-title-5 product-box__features-text u-margin-0">
        <span>
            <span data-fees-annual-value="">$0</span>
        </span>
    </dd>
</div>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

soup.select_one('span[data-fees-annual-value]').text
```

#### Output

```
$0
```

Comment: this is fixed my issue because directly point that select_one('tag[attribute]') grab the entire line and pull the text with .text, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find element by text, use `string` instead of `title`:

```
element.find("span", string=re.compile('$'))
```

Output:

```
<span data-fees-annual-value="">$0</span>
```

Comment: sorry i didn't mention that it's large html page and it pulls out all stuff for me. but good one to learn for if the page only 1 condition which is <span> and text $. thank you for that